# Coffeescript parameters for statements

Tags: coffeescript

I am having hard time finding how to do something like this in coffeescript

`Javascript output`

```
require("module")({

})
```

Comment: What's wrong with `require('module')({ })`?

Comment: I have to add all these curly braces myself , i am looking for coffee way

Comment: If you want it to be more CoffeeScript'ish, you could write it like this: `(require 'module') {}`.

Comment: http://js2.coffee/ . require('module') {} . there are not coffee way probably

Comment: but `(require 'module')` and then indent object declaration will work without parentheses

Answer (score 2):

This is, naturally, a matter of opinion.

I believe it **pays to be explicit.**

So, CoffeeScript or not, I would recommend the following:

```
options = {}
require('module')(options)
```

The CoffeeScript community style guide is rather subjective on the [matter of using parentheses](https://github.com/polarmobile/coffeescript-style-guide#functions):

> When calling functions, choose to omit or include parentheses in such
>   a way that optimizes for readability. Keeping in mind that
>   "readability" can be subjective, the following examples demonstrate
>   cases where parentheses have been omitted or included in a manner that
>   the community deems to be optimal:

```
baz 12

brush.ellipse x: 10, y: 20 # Braces can also be omitted or included for readability

foo(4).bar(8)

obj.value(10, 20) / obj.value(20, 10)

print inspect value

new Tag(new Value(a, b), new Arg(c))
```